# spark error in column type

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe column,called 'SupplierId' ,typed as a string, with a lot of digits, but also some characters chain.
(ex: `['123','456','789',......,'abc']`).
I formatted this column as a string using

```python
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
df=df.withColumn('SupplierId',df['SupplierId'].cast(StringType())
```

So I check it is treated as a string using:

```python
df.printSchema()
```

and I get:

```python
root
 |-- SupplierId: string (nullable = true)
```

But when I try to convert to Pandas, or just to use `df.collect()`,
I obtain the following error:

```python
An error occurred while calling o516.collectToPython. : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:

Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 11, servername.ops.somecompany.local, executor 3): 
ava.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException:
Exception parsing 'CPD160001' into a IntegerType$ for column "SupplierId":
Unable to deserialize value using com.somecompany.spark.parsers.text.converters.IntegerConverter.
The value being deserialized was: CPD160001
```

So it seems Spark treats the value of this column as integers.
I have tried using UDF to force convert to string with python, but it still doesn't work.
Do you have any idea what could cause this error?

Comment: when I call df.printSchema(), I have:
root
 |-- SupplierId: string (nullable = true)

Comment: You should add the above comment about the `printSchema()` as part of the question. Can you try to create a [mcve] so we can try to reproduce the error?

Answer (score 1):

Please do share a sample of your actual data, as your issue cannot be reproduced with toy ones:

```python
spark.version
#  u'2.2.0'

from pyspark.sql import Row
df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(1, 2, '3'),
                            Row(4, 5, 'a'),
                            Row(7, 8, '9')],
                            ['x1', 'x2', 'id'])  

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- x1: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- x2: long (nullable = true) 
#  |-- id: string (nullable = true) 

df.collect()
# [Row(x1=1, x2=2, id=u'3'), Row(x1=4, x2=5, id=u'a'), Row(x1=7, x2=8, id=u'9')]

import pandas as pd
df_pandas = df.toPandas()
df_pandas
#   x1 x2 id 
# 0  1  2  3
# 1  4  5  a
# 2  7  8  9
```